# STAX for printing XML

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to create XML using STAX

The below code works great. In stand alone this XML gets printed on the console.

```
    XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

    // create XMLEventWriter
    XMLEventWriter eventWriter = outputFactory
        .createXMLEventWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
```

The issue here is that dont need to print on console or on file but I need XML InputStream as final value.
Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    XMLStreamWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(bos);
    // ... write here
    InputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
```